# Converted Datetime format is changed if change site language

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a website which is in two languages (English & Russian).

I am try to convert string to datetime so for that i have used this code

```
string dts = form["startdatetime"];
string ets = form["enddatetime"];

DateTime? dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dts) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dts, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
DateTime? et = string.IsNullOrEmpty(ets) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(ets, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

So issue happen is i will explain with example. i have date of 12/30/2015 & selected language is Eng. & convert `DateTime? Dt value is 30/12/2015 10:00:00`. Now issue is happen when i changed language English to Russia it will converted above same given date to `DateTime? Dt value is 30.12.2015 10:00:00`. I didn't understand why its happen.

Is any one have solution of it? Or any one has face this issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Those are the same as a *value*.
Only difference is their *textual* representation when you try to get their string representation.

English culture (*I assume `en-US`*) uses `/` as a [`DateSeparator`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) but Russian culture (*I assume `ru-RU`*) uses `.`.

For example, if you get your string representation like `.ToString()` without providing any `IFormatProvider` in your code, this method will use your `CurrentCulture` settings and this date separator will be `/` or `.` depending you set english or russian culture.

But since you didn't even show *how* you get these string representations, we can not help you more.

Comment: my converted datetime is shown in formate of 30.12.2015 10:00:00 this if russian languge selected & it will be display in datetime picker & if user wants to change date than again it will submit start date but if he didn't edit enddate it will give error while convert to date time in below given code` DateTime? dt = string.IsNullOrEmpty(dts) ? (DateTime?)null : DateTime.Parse(dts, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` error is string is not recogniz.

Comment: @Div This is a different problem than you asking in your question. You asked why I get different string representations of the same value in your question but you asking why I _can't_ parse this string to DateTime. Anyway, `DateTime.Parse` uses standard date and time formats of your `IFormatProvider` (it is `InvariantCulture` on your example). Looks like your `dts` is not a standard format of `InvariantCulture`. We can't know more since you didn't _even_ tell us what is the value of `dts` exactly.

Comment: value of dts is 12/30/2015 10:00:00.

Comment: @Div I don't think so because `var dt = DateTime.Parse("12/30/2015 10:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` parses fine.

Comment: due to this different string representation i got this error

Comment: so how to parse string to nullable datetime? i have got value in dts is 12/30/2015 10:00:00

Comment: @Div As I said, you _can_ parse it as `var dt = DateTime.Parse("12/30/2015 10:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` and then you can directly assing it to `DateTime?` like `DateTime? ndt = dt;`

Answer (score 2):

The way a `DateTime` is converted to string depends on the systems Culture. It seems that you're not only changing the language but also the Culture, and that Russian and English differ in how a DateTime is written.

One solution could be to make sure that the `DateTime` is converted to string using `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`.

```
DateTimeObj.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use universal time if you want to handle dates reliably across time zones, see [DateTime.ToUniversalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Use a [custom date and time formatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx) if you want to control the format across cultures to be a specific format. You could create an extension method for this, but generally people in a specific region expect to see dates in a familiar format, hence the reason why date formats are culture specific.

Listen to Matt Johnson on .Net Rocks for a great overview of dates on [this show](https://www.dotnetrocks.com/?show=1230)

Also take a look at the [Noda Date/Time API](http://nodatime.org/), very useful for complex date and time scenarios.